# Nginx SSL-Termination or SSL-Passthrough depending on domain

Tags: nginx

I have a server running VirtualBox (host machine) with several virtual machines, one VM per project. Each project has its own domain, and all these domains point to the server's IP address. The host machine cannot directly communicate with the virtual machines. To enable communication, various port-forwarding rules are set up within VirtualBox, allowing communication through specific ports only. Both the host machine and the virtual machines have Nginx installed, and the virtual machines also have Docker to run certain applications.

The objective is for the Nginx on the host machine to redirect traffic to the Nginx on the virtual machines based on the domain. For instance, all requests to *.projectA.com will be redirected to the Nginx on VM1, while requests to *.projectB.com will be redirected to the Nginx on VM2. For projectB, the SSL certificates are provided by the host machine's Nginx. However, for project1, the intention is for the SSL certificates to be delivered by the Nginx running on VM1.

The following image summarizes what I have described:
[Infrastructure Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbVsX.png)

I've noticed that one way to ensure SSL certificates are delivered by the guest machine is to avoid SSL termination in the Nginx on the host machine using the "stream" block. However, I can't configure both the "stream" block and "http" on port 443 simultaneously.

Assuming I want Nginx on the host machine to listen on both ports 80 and 443, is there a way to configure Nginx so that requests to *.projectA.com use SSL passthrough while the rest undergo SSL termination, with the host machine's Nginx providing the certificates?

I have tried to add a stream configuration file so that all requests made to `subX.projectA.com` or `subY.projectA.com` use SSL passthrough, while for the rest (i.e., other projects different from projectA), SSL termination is used. The configuration for the other projects is handled through HTTP blocks listening on ports 80 and 443. This is my stream configuration:

```
stream {

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        subX.projectA.com backend1;
        subY.projectA.com backend2;
        default https_default_backend;
    }

    upstream backend1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:6612;
    }

    upstream backend2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:6612;
    }

    upstream https_default_backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $name;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

When running nginx the following error appears:

```
[emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I want to emphasize that my goal is for the certificates of *.projectA.com to be delivered by VM1 nginx. Any solution that addresses this issue, whether or not it involves SSL passthrough, is acceptable. It's also worth noting that the certificates for VM1 are different for each Docker container and are automatically generated by [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion). That's why I can't have those certificates created in the configuration folder of the host's Nginx. In addition I am trying to achieve the objective without changing the nginx configuration for the rest of the projects.